# Printing from phone

Tags: data-connection, printing

I do not have a computer, just a printer. I have a .docx file saved on my Samasung Galaxy Tab 2, and need to print it ASAP. How do I do it?

Comment: Your printer needs to be compatible firstly. Install [Xodo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader) app, open the document and select the printer from print options